# Swift - Change a UIImageView when an odd or even number is received as an answer to a multiplication product

Tags: ios, swift

I want to change the imageView to a different picture, when the product results in an odd number or even number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should work for you:

```swift
class YourViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

    func updateImageView(for number: Int) {
        if number % 2 == 0 {
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "funnierImage")
        } else {
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "funnyImage")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func randomizerButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(2)
        updateImageView(for: randomNumber)
    }
}
```